# How to create a custom AST using visitor in Antlr

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to use the visitor pattern to walk the ParserRuleContext and build an AST using predefined nodes.

In my grammar I have the following rule:

```
expr
    : loop
    | block
```

I would like to produce an AST that has the following structure:

```
    exprNode
      / 
loopNode
```

The `BaseVisitor` generated by Antlr has the following method in it:

```
public T visitExpr(MyParser.ExprContext ctx) { return visitChildren(ctx); }
```

The `ASTBuilder` overrides this method and creates a `exprNode`. To this `exprNode` I want to append either a `loopNode` or a `blockNode` by calling my overrode versions of `visitLoop` and `visitBlock`. The problem I have is that I don't know the identity of the `expr`, as I only obtained `exprContext` from the parent. How do I check which invocation of the `expr` rule was used?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want to append a `LoopNode` or `BlockNode` to an `ExprNode`? How exactly do these classes relate to each other and what does "append" mean in this context? Normally I would assume that `BlockNode` and `LoopNode` would simply be subclasses of the abstract class `ExprNode` and you'd want `visitExpr` to return one of those - not append anything to anything.

Comment: That is more or less what I want to do. Sorry for the vague explanation. How would I decide which of the two concrete nodes (`BlockNode` or `LoopNode`) is to be returned by `visitExpr`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't override `visitExpr`. Just override `visitLoop` and `visitBlock`.

The auto-generated `visitExpr` will call the appropriate one of those two (via `visitChildren`) and return whatever `visitLoop` or `visitBlock` returned. So as long as you override those methods to return the proper result, `visitExpr` will also return the proper result automatically.

Comment: To clarify: I also have `methodDefinition : ID PAREN_OPEN ....... expr ........` in my grammar. In the `visitMethodDefinition` method I want to create a `MethodNode` that has a field for an `ExprNode` (abstract class). Should I have `visitMethodDefinition` call `visitExpr(ctx.expr())` and cast the result to the abstract `ExprNode`?

Comment: @JanParzydło As a rule of thumb, I'd only ever call `visit`, not specific `visitFoo`  methods. But yes, you can call `visit(ctx.expr())` and then cast the result to `ExprNode`. Alternatively, you could use a dedicated `ExpressionVisitor` that extends `YourLangBaseVisitor<ExprNode>`, so you don't have to cast anything.

Answer (score 0):

Labeling the rule alts provides convenience contexts for determining identity:

```
expr
    : loop   #loopExpr
    | block  #blockExpr
    ;
```

The generated parser will now contain `LoopExprContext extends ExprContext` and `BlockExprContext extends ExprContext` classes with appropriately behaved visitor enter and exit methods.

Comment: Even without the labelling my parser's `ExprContext` class contains `loop()` and `block()` that return the right context. When creating the AST, at some point I enter an `ExprContext`, this is where I want to decide on the identity of the expression and return one of the nodes corresponding to `loop` or `block`. How do I do that?

Comment: When you label, you essentially ignore the base context (`ExprContext`, at least in the Java implementation, is the common superclass for both `LoopExprContext` and `BlockExprContext`). So, when the visitor visits the `loop` alt of the `expr` rule, the visit methods of `LoopExprContext` are called as, in effect, a simple specialization of the `ExprContext` visit methods.